# TeXStudio on Mac has issues with characters while on Windows doesn't

Tags: texstudio, mac

My document contains Phoenician characters like . When I open it using TeXstudio on Mac, they appear as rectangles, but when I open them on my Windows 11 (Parallels virtual machine), they appear as they should.

TeXstudio on Windows has Consolas as editor font, so I went to the fonts folder, copied the `.ttf` files from there and installed the font on Mac, then chose it as editor font, however characters still appear as rectangles.

I attach the screenshots of the source code.

[image][image]

Comment: Please, provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: @FHZ MWE of what? This seems to be a problem with the editor